# Find a nonnegative vector orthogonal to a set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, linear-programming

I am trying to solve this problem:

> Given a set of $m$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $m < n$, $$(a_i)_{1 \le i \le m}$$ for a fixed index $j$ can we compute a vector $u$ in polynomial time such that $u^Ta_i = 0$, $u \ge 0$ and $u_j = 1$?

I know that we can solve this problem with linear programming but to have an exact solution with polynomial time I don't know how.

It will be also good if I can model the problem with a graph problem.
Can any one help me ?

Comment: Try Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization.

Comment: How can I make sure that the vector is nonnegative

Comment: That constraint doesn't make sense. A vector is not positive or negative - it cannot be compared to zero.

Comment: Positive component by component

Comment: I think now it makes sense

Comment: I don't think Gram-Schmidt is going to work for you if that's the requirement. Alas, I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: Linear programs can be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: How can you solved linear program ?